# How to implement Emoji inside a messaging service like SendBird? (Web-Base App none-native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sendbird

Hello lads/las I am working on a project which trigger "SendBird" messaging service; I implemented all the basic functions but right now I am trying to use Emoji for ease of use inside it. Have no idea where to start, any suggestion Appreciate.

Need to mention I need free license service if you are suggesting any API's. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ReactEmoji.

Here's a link to the github repository : https://github.com/banyan/react-emoji.

Just do `npm install react-emoji --save` to save it as a dependency to your project. Then import it to your project `import ReactEmoji from 'react-emoji'`.

Then just to `{ReactEmoji.emojify(*your message here*)}` . The emojify function will render your message and turn it into an object, which is going to display as an icon later.

Answer (score 0):

Unicode emojis should be supported on SendBird by default; unless your browser does not support them natively, they should be rendered without any problems.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but do you know anyway of using unicode to be cross-platform. Because the project is suppose to be Cross-platform.?

Comment: @Milan well, most modern platforms should support emojis. [Here](http://caniemoji.com/) is a handy link to check emoji support across platforms and versions.